# Advance Product Manager (exporting issues)!

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I am stuck in a issue (export Products in CSV), I am using an extension "Advance Product Manager" in magento, when I export products then it gives the default behavior of the CSV format, it gives the values of (category, attribute_set, brand etc) fields in id form not in text form. the issue is that I need those values in text form, how can I achieve that goal. I had conversation with extension author he said it exports the default behavior of magento as it is.

ScreenShot for the above described issue, in which you clearly see what I need right now:

[image: In this screenshot you can see clearly what i need right now!!!]

Thanks in advance...